# Geocoding mobile app

Tags: android, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I am an entry level programmer and i want to create an app, in which an address converts to a specific latitude and longtitude. Is there an easy way to do this? I read a few things about geocoder. Could you please describe to me, where and how?

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with GeoCoder. Here is the code for rescue ;)

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address> address;
GeoPoint p1 = null;

try {
    address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
    if (address==null) {
       return null;
    }
    Address location=address.get(0);
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    p1 = new GeoPoint((double) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                      (double) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

    return p1;
    }
}
```

where strAddress is the actual address you want long and lat.

Happy Coding :)